# How to change colors of each side of 3D Sierpinski Gasket using color picker?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have create a 3D Sierpinski Gasket with WebGL. I am still very new on this. I know how to change the color of each triangles, but I don't know how to change the colors using color picker(HTML5 color picker).

This is where the colors of the triangle:

```
function triangle( a, b, c, color )
{
    // add colors and vertices for one triangle

     var baseColors = [
        vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    ]; //Colors triangle RGB

    colors.push( baseColors[color] );
    points.push( a );
    colors.push( baseColors[color] );
    points.push( b );
    colors.push( baseColors[color] );
    points.push( c );
}
```

This is how the triangle looks like
3D Sierpinski Gasket:
[image: 1]

How can I change the colors of each triangle using color picker?

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need some way of selecting which triangles you want to set but to make it easy to code you could just use a starting and ending triangle index

Example:

```js
const numColors = 10;
const colors = new Array(numColors * 3).fill(0.5);

function setColors() {
  let start = document.querySelector('#start').value;
  let end = document.querySelector('#end').value;
  if (start > end) {
    const t = start; start = end; end = t;
  }
  // bound start and end
  start = Math.min(numColors - 1, Math.max(0, start));
  end = Math.min(numColors - 1, Math.max(0, end));
  const colorStr = document.querySelector('#color').value;
  const parts = /#(..)(..)(..)/.exec(colorStr).slice(1, 4);
  const color = parts.map(s => parseInt(s, 16) / 255);
  
  for (let i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
    const offset = i * 3;
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
      colors[offset + j] = color[j];
    }
  }

  // here you'd re-upload the colors using
  // gl.bufferData or gl.bufferSubData
  // and then re-render
  showColors();
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', setColors);


// -- not important, just some way to display the colors --
const rgb = (r, g, b) => `rgb(${r * 255}, ${g * 255}, ${b * 255})`;
function showColors() {
  const out = document.querySelector('#out')
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i += 3) {
    const id = `c${i}`
    let elem = out.querySelector(`#${id}`);
    if (!elem) {
       elem = document.createElement('div');
       elem.id = id;
       out.appendChild(elem);
    }
    elem.style.backgroundColor = rgb(...colors.slice(i, i + 3));
  }
}

showColors();
```

```css
#out>div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="number" id="start" value="0"><span>: start</span></div>
<div><input type="number" id="end" value="0"><span>: end</span></div>
<div><input type="color" id="color" value="#FF0000"><span>: color</span></div>
<div><button type="button">apply</button></div>
<p></p>
<div id="out"></div>
```

If you actual want to be able to click on triangles that's already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwebgl%5D+picking). Also [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-picking.html)

Comment: Thank you for this! Actually I want to change the colors of the side like in the picture, it was red, blue and green. I want to change the colors based on color picker.

Comment: So then apply the code in my answer to every 3rd triangle's vertex colors.